# Google Calendar API: Calendar usage limit message occur and accessNotConfigured

Tags: android, api, google-calendar-api

```
403 Forbidden
 {
  "code": 403,
   "errors": [
     {
       "domain": "usageLimits",
       "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.",
       "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
     }
   ],
   "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
```

I have already activated the api for google calendar. What can I do with that? I have also set the key but I am still getting error.

Comment: Google is asking about its errors!? WE'RE DOOMED!!!

Comment: Chances are it takes time for your key to get activated.

Comment: @JoxTraex hey but i created it b4 3 month ago.but now its not working. so plz tell me if any solutions

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse to build the application directly, you need to use debug key SHA1 for credential. You can find that in preferences > android > build.

Comment: can u plz how can we use this and what is the procedure?

Comment: Go to the Google developer console, select your project, click "credential" on the left, create a new client id.

Comment: we have already created the client id. after that what can i do?what is the use of client id?

Comment: Now android developers don't need to set the client id in the application. It just letting Google know which app is accessing the api. If you don't know what to do, why don't you start with the sample code. http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html